# Issues in passing extra properties to a gradle task

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am having trouble in passing extra properties to a gradle task. Here is my build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
}


ext {
    dir = ''
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

group = 'group'
version = 'version'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.4'
}

repositories {

}
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()

}
```

As you can see, I have an extra property as dir initialized to be ''. Now, here is my task

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    File myDir = project.dir

    @TaskAction
    public void action() {
    }
}
```

My plugin

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    def void apply(Project project) {
        project.tasks.create("myTask", MyTask)
    }

}
```

And this unit test

```
public class TestPlugin {
    @Test
    public void testPlugin() {
        Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
        project.getPlugins().apply(TestPlugin.class);
        Assert.assertTrue(project.getProject().getTasks().findByName("myTask") instanceof MyTask);
    }
}
```

Now when I run the test, it shows the error that it couldn't find the dir property.

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you passing the plugin class to `project.tasks.create`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth. Made a mistake when copying. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Your `build.gradle` script and your test are not linked in any way. In your test, you create a clean new project and the first (and only) thing you do is to apply your custom plugin, which then creates your custom task. The task property `myDir` is going to be set, but the called property `dir` does not exist in the project, so the exception is thrown.

You can either define the extra property `dir` for your test project ...

```
Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build();
project.ext.dir = ''
project.getPlugins().apply(TestPlugin.class);
Assert.assertTrue(project.getProject().getTasks().findByName("myTask") instanceof MyTask);
```

... or apply your new plugin to the project of your `build.gradle` script (when you are done).

Comment: project.ext.dir = '' doesn't work. It doesn't find the ext property